# slot and slot-scope Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to migrate an Vue2 app to Vue3,

I read that you have to change in general as follow :

```html
<template slot="slotName">
<!-- becomes -->
<template #slotName>

<template slot="slotName" slot-scope="scope">
<!-- becomes -->
<template v-slot:slotName="scope">
```

but in the app I have a few particular cases I don't know what I am supposed to do :

```html
<template slot="slotName" slot-scope="scope, index, record">
<!-- becomes ??? -->
<template v-slot:slotName="scope, index, record">

<template :key="index" v-for="(col, index) in columns" v-if="col.scopedSlots" :slot="col.dataIndex" slot-scope="text, record, index">
<!-- I have no clue how to change this -->
```

PS : I didn't code the app, am just asked to try to migrate it to Vue 3 and I don't know much about Vue, so please try to explain a little bit if possible, thank you !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Vue 3 is better than 2, the velocity is impressive, if you have possibility, change for than.

If you don't have big experience use nuxt, you need to use in that way

```
<!-- Vue 2 -->
<template slot="slotName" slot-scope="scope, index, record">
<!-- Vue 3 -->
<template v-slot:slotName="{ scope, index, record }">
```

and this

```
<!-- Vue 2 -->
<template :key="index" v-for="(col, index) in columns" v-if="col.scopedSlots" :slot="col.dataIndex" slot-scope="text, record, index">
<!-- Vue 3 -->
<template v-for="(col, index) in columns" :key="index" v-if="col.scopedSlots">
  <template v-slot:[col.dataIndex]="{ text, record, index }">
```

On Vue 3, v-slot:[col.dataIndex] is used to bind the slot with the data.

You have possiblity to  destructure the slot props using { } in the v-slot directive.

Comment: Unfortunalty I am limited to only use Vue in the app !

Comment: No problem! Nuxt is a framework for vue. Did I clear your doubts? Do you have any more questions?

Comment: Yes you answered my question, I don't have a warning anymore now ! Thanks a lot